# How to protect against a short circuit fail in 12VDC X capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, 12v, short-circuit, fuses

When adding an X capacitor for simple line filtering in a 12V DC electronics project, how would you add protection against an unlikely short circuit failure in that capacitor?
Is it as simple as a fuse or something more interesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need any protection for X caps, they are designed not to short.  If you have a concern, use an X1 instead of the more common X2.  They are made to an even higher standard.
However, using a fuse will protect from other failures that are much more likely.